# sketch app using pt only for text sizes and seemingly for everything else?

Tags: sketch-3, sketchapp

the sketch fonts are set in PT

now I want to write a web app using bootstrap 4. So I am used to using pixels / em / rem for fonts and distances. I see *no* value using PT. Points seem to be for print media

so what is the proper way to convert pt to pixels? the stuff I found on the net does not really seem to be correct.

of course, sketch app is some mac only tool. And afaik there seems no way to export it to other apps like adobe illustrator or photoshop. At least, not properly that it would be useful.

bonus question: scrolling in sketch is horrible, there is no scroll bar and the scrolling is dead slow. Any advice on that?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting read: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/199/point-vs-pixel-what-is-the-difference

> In CSS
>
> A pt is 1/72 of an in, and a px is 1/96 of an in.
>
> A px is therefore 0.75 pt [[source]](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#x39).
>
> In CSS, everything is somewhat abstracted, so a unit such as a "pt" is
>   not necessarily one point in physical size, especially on a screen, an
>   "in" is not necessarily one inch in size, and so forth. Even a "px" is
>   no longer necessarily one pixel in size anymore: Everything is scaled
>   to be consistent with a hypothetical 96 ppi device viewed at normal
>   reading distance, meaning that on screens that differ significantly
>   from 96 ppi or from normal reading distance, everything will be
>   scaled, but still maintain the same relationships ie a pt will still
>   be 1.33334 px units and still be 1/72 of an in unit.
>
> In print
>
> In print, a point was traditionally somewhere from around 1/67 of an
>   inch to 1/72.5 of an inch.
>
> In digital mediums, it has become a de-facto standard for a point to
>   be exactly 1/72 of an inch nowadays, though there are still
>   alternative measurements in less common use which vary slightly from
>   1/72, but not by much.
>
> In print, you don't usually measure in pixels, because they are a
>   technical detail about the target printer or device that are not an
>   absolute measurement. For instance, a design may be printed at 125
>   dpi, 300 dpi or at 1200 dpi and still be the same physical dimensions.

As for scrolling in sketch, did you try to hold spacebar while dragging (hand tool)?